# Creating a Forms-Based MFC Application

Tags: c++, mfc

I created a MainFrm using Visual Studio (MFC). When I press "open" to open the `txt` file,  I cannot review and edit content. When I press "new", I also cannot edit content.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, the AppWizard creates a skeleton for an application. It includes enough to create the windows being shown, but does nothing with the contents of those windows--that's where each application is unique. In one case you might support editing text, in another, line graphics, and in a third display photographs, etc.

Text editing is common enough that it can/will support text editing out of the box (so to speak). When you get close to the end of the app wizard pages, one of them will ask about the base class to use for each of the classes in your application. Toward the top, select "View", then toward the bottom change the Base Class from CView to CEditView:

[image]

[Note: this is with VS 2019. The exact appearance varies between versions of VS.]

Proceed and build the application, and it will now have (rather minimal) support for text editing, something on the order of Notepad:

[image]

You will need to add a bit more if you want to be able to select the font, control word wrapping, etc., like Notepad supports though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jerry Coffin. It is ok.